# Custom Keras Layer Troubles

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, keras, softmax

Hate to ask a question like this on machine learning but googling has yielded nothing useful - I've just found 2 github threads where people on super old versions of tensorflow got the same error *message*, but not for the same reason im getting it.

Basically; I'm implementing this facial point paper for work; and it uses spatial softargmax (just a layer that takes in a stack of images a lot like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MCaYh.png) - and it returns the most "intense part" of the image (so just the x,y coordinates of the white blob). It takes in an array with 68 of these images (all 1 channel, so the array is 100x100x68) and it gives 68 pairs of x,y coordinates for each one - these end up being the facial points.

The layer I have written in keras to do this is;

```py
class spatial_softArgmax(Layer):

        def __init__(self, output_dim, **kwargs):
                self.output_dim = output_dim
                super(spatial_softArgmax, self).__init__(**kwargs)


        def build(self, input_shape):
                # Create a trainable weight variable for this layer.
                # self.kernel = self.add_weight(name='kernel', shape=(input_shape[1], self.output_dim), initializer='uniform', trainable=True)
                super(spatial_softArgmax, self).build(input_shape)  # Be sure to call this somewhere!

        def call(self, x):
            #print "input to ssm:  " + str(x.shape)
            maps = layers.spatial_softmax(x, data_format='NCHW')
            #maps = tf.reshape(maps, [2, 68])
            #print "output of ssm: " + str(maps.shape)
            return maps

        def get_config(self):
                config = super(spatial_softArgmax, self).get_config()
                config['output_dim'] = self.output_dim
                config['input_shape'] = self.input_shape
                return config

        def compute_output_shape(self, input_shape):
                return (input_shape[0], self.output_dim)
```

It isn't working though; like at all; I keep getting this error that says 'None Values not supported' whenever i try to start training (training begins if i replace it with a dense - so the problem is definitely this layer) - which makes me think that my layer isn't returning anything?? I dug around in the TF code a bit around where this exception is raise but didn't really find much...

If you guys see anything wrong with my layer just by glancing i'd really appreciate it if you'd let me know; I *need* to have this network training overnight tonight.

EDIT: I've removed the self.kernel line; but am now getting:

```py
x,y shape (12000, 3, 100, 100) - (12000, 68, 2)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "architecture.py", line 58, in <module>
    model.fit(x, y, batch_size=1, epochs=50, verbose=1)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1522, in fit
    batch_size=batch_size)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1382, in _standardize_user_data
    exception_prefix='target')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 132, in _standardize_input_data
    str(array.shape))
ValueError: Error when checking target: expected spatial_soft_argmax_1 to have 2 dimensions, but got array with shape (12000, 68, 2)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've added a weight `self.kernel` but didn't use it anywhere in your `call` function.

Therefore, TF is unable to compute gradient for the parameters in `self.kernel`. In this case, the gradient will be `None` and that's why you're seeing an error complaining about operating on `None` values.

Removing the line `self.kernel = self.add_weight(...)` should make it work.

Comment: I removed it but now I am getting another error; I've edited the question and put the new error at the end.

Comment: Also I changed the softargmax function to use tensorflow's built in softargmax function. my dataset is 12,000 in size; which is where i think the 12,000 is coming from...

Comment: Your layer specifies an output shape of `(input_shape[0], self.output_dim)` (which is `(12000, 136)` I guess?) but your `y` is of shape `(12000, 68, 2)`. So either reshape the output value of `call` to `(12000, 68, 2)`, or reshape `y` into `(12000, 136)`.

Comment: I'm not quite sure this reshaping will correspond well to your loss function, though, as I don't really know what loss you (or the original paper) are using. I'm just suggesting a way to get past the error.

Comment: thank you so much for all of the help so far. Both y and the output of call are (12000, 136) - however i still get "ValueError: Error when checking target: expected spatial_soft_argmax_1 to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (12000, 136)"... When I add a tf.reshape(filters, [136]) to call (filters is the output of softmax) - i get this error again:
  `File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/tensor_util.py", line 371, in make_tensor_proto
    raise ValueError("None values not supported.")
ValueError: None values not supported.`

Comment: EDIT: GOT IT WORKING!!! I just had to do the reshape changes you said and uncomment that kernel line... thank you SO much for all of your help!! seriously!

Comment: @RobbieBarrat did you update your solution in the OP or maybe create a separate solution? I am also having trouble with creating a custom layer.

Comment: @Moondra ah... I created a separate solution (didnt update the OP) - this was for an old job I had so I no longer have access to the code; really sorry.